# Why this doesn't get imported

Tags: reactjs, typescript, file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRdeY.png)
This doesn't get imported, why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is VSC telling you that you are not using these two imports in your file.